# How to get the node id the comment is attached to in hook_comment_insert?

Tags: 8, hooks, comments

How can I get the node `id` the comment is attached to in `hook_comment_insert`?

I tried the following code:

```
function mymodule_comment_insert(Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityInterface $entity) {
  if ($entity->bundle() == 'comment_custom' && $entity->get('entity_type')->value == 'node') {

    // Below returns empty, because "$entity->get('entity_id')->value" is empty.
    $node = Node::load($entity->get('entity_id')->value);

    // No luck with this one too.
    $node = \Drupal::routeMatch()->getParameter('node');

  }
}
```

Comment: i wanted to pick up the "node" to which the comment is being attached (and react accordingly).

Answer (score 6):

the correct way to load nid is,

`$entity->get('entity_id')->target_id`

and not

`$entity->get('entity_id')->value`

In case of doubt which key to use,

try,

`$entity->get('entity_id')->getValue()`

and inspect the returned value.

Answer (score 5):

This is a late answer based on another question flagged as duplicate of this one.

The Comment entity has some helpful methods for getting back the entity it's associated with.

[CommentInterface::getCommentedEntity](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21comment%21src%21Entity%21Comment.php/function/Comment%3A%3AgetCommentedEntity/8.7.x) should get the entity object that the comment is attached to.

So

```
if ($entity instanceof \Drupal\comment\CommentInterface) {
   $commentedEntity = $entity->getCommentedEntity();
   if ($commentedEntity && $commentedEntity instanceof \Drupal\node\NodeInterface) {
     // The entity that the comment is attached to is a node.
     // Do something with the commented entity.
   }
}
```

Comment: That is the proper answer