# Node ID from hook_comment_insert

Tags: 8

I need the ID of the node the inserted comment is attached to. This is what I have tried:

```
function my-module_comment_insert(Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityInterface $entity)
{

   // According to https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/145823/how-do-i-get-the-current-node-id
    $node = \Drupal::routeMatch()->getParameter('node');
    if ($node instanceof \Drupal\node\NodeInterface) {
        $nid = $node->id();
    }
    drupal_set_message("The vaue is " . print_r($nid), 'warning');
}
```

But... The value I get is "1", while it should be (according to node URL) "55". Or am I using drupal_set_message for debugging the wrong way?

I also tried **$entity->get('entity_id')->target_id** (according to:  [How to get the node id the comment is attached to in hook_comment_insert?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/206903/how-to-get-the-node-id-the-comment-is-attached-to-in-hook-comment-insert)) or **\Drupal::routeMatch()->getRawParameter('node')**, but I always get "1" and I'm positive that the website cache has been cleared.

Comment: I saw that, but "$entity->get('entity_id')->value" gives me back "1" too.

Comment: Have you cleared cache?

Comment: Yes, I did clear cache

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`print_r($variable)` does not return anything useful, it just outputs text (which it does successfully, so it returns boolean TRUE [which is rendered as `1` when printed]). Your `drupal_set_message` basically does something like `echo ($string . $boolean . $string)`

Use `print_r($variable, true)` to return the output of the print_r to the calling function, instead of rendering it.

See https://www.php.net/manual/function.print-r.php

Answer (score 0):

Look here https://git.drupalcode.org/project/drupal/blob/8.8.x/core/modules/comment/src/Entity/Comment.php#L369
https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21comment%21src%21Entity%21Comment.php/function/Comment%3A%3AgetCommentedEntity/8.2.x

and... =) [How to get the node id the comment is attached to in hook_comment_insert?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/206903/how-to-get-the-node-id-the-comment-is-attached-to-in-hook-comment-insert)

Comment: https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21includes%21bootstrap.inc/function/drupal_set_message/8.7.x

in Drupal 8.5.0 and will be removed before Drupal 9.0.0. Use \Drupal\Core\Messenger\MessengerInterface::addMessage() instead. `\Drupal::messenger()->addStatus('Message');`