# How to get comment cid in hook_comment_insert?

Tags: comments, 9

I've read the answers to [How to get the node id the comment is attached to in hook_comment_insert?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/q/206903/12076) and found how to extract the `nid` of the node the comment is associated with.

However, I also need to get the `cid` of the comment itself from inside `hook_comment_insert()`. How do I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All entities have an `id()` method:

```
$cid = $entity->id();
```

Comment: Clive's answer is correct.  It would be worth adding a link to the documentation to give more context to the answer though. Key things are that the hook fires *after* the entity has been saved and that you can't save any edits in the hook. i.e., it's useful to examine and react to the insert. https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Entity%21entity.api.php/function/hook_ENTITY_TYPE_insert/9.2.x

Comment: Thanks! Also thanks to @Gold for the link to the API docs.